# Updating sldstyle based on user choice

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, colormap

I use sldstyle to create a discrete colormap for plotting images in Google Earth Engine. Like this:

```
var assimvalue = 1; // desired upper limit.
//set up the 11 intervals
var assimstep1=-(assimvalue/5*5).toFixed(2);
var assimstep2=-(assimvalue/5*4).toFixed(2);
var assimstep3=-(assimvalue/5*3).toFixed(2);
var assimstep4=-(assimvalue/5*2).toFixed(2);
var assimstep5=-(assimvalue/5*1).toFixed(2);
var assimstep6=0;
var assimstep7=(assimvalue/5*1).toFixed(2);
var assimstep8=(assimvalue/5*2).toFixed(2);
var assimstep9=(assimvalue/5*3).toFixed(2);
var assimstep10=(assimvalue/5*4).toFixed(2);
var assimstep11=(assimvalue/5*5).toFixed(2);
var assim_sld_intervals =
  '<RasterSymbolizer>' +
    '<ColorMap type="intervals" extended="false" >' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#78281F" quantity="' +assimstep1+ '" label="0"/>' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#B03A2E" quantity="' +assimstep2+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#E74C3C" quantity="' +assimstep3+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#F1948A" quantity="' +assimstep4+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#FADBD8" quantity="' +assimstep5+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="' +assimstep6+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#D6EAF8" quantity="' +assimstep7+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#85C1E9" quantity="' +assimstep8+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#3498DB" quantity="' +assimstep9+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#2874A6" quantity="' +assimstep10+ '"  />' +
      '<ColorMapEntry color="#1B4F72" quantity="' +assimstep11+ '"  />' +
    '</ColorMap>' +
  '</RasterSymbolizer>'; 

[snip]
var assimdeltahslayer = ui.Map.Layer(assimdeltahs.sldStyle(assim_sld_intervals),{},'CSO Assim Delta Hs',false);
layers.add(assimdeltahslayer);
```

This works great, and creates a very attractive colormap with ten blue bins. Well, now I am trying to use a slider to allow the user to select the 'max' value. Based on this choice, the intervals get recalculated and I want the image to be replotted with the new color limits. This is where I am stuck.

With continuous colormaps it is easy, as you just use setvisparams inside the function that is listening for a change to the slider. With sldstyle, I am unsure how to do this.

I can recalculate the new intervals, no problem, but how do I 'update' them?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `sldStyle()` with a new document, you get a completely different image. While you can update the visualization parameters of a layer, you cannot replace the image. You'll have to replace the whole layer. How depends on specifics you didn't include in your question.

Instead of using `sldStyle()`, you could use visParams with a palette. When you have non-continuous categories, you can fill in the "missing" values in the palette. There's another advantage of doing this, you don't change the image, and inspecting pixels will give you the actual image value instead of an RGB value.

```
var colorByValue = {
  0: '282828',
  20: 'FFBB22',
  30: 'FFFF4C',
  ...
}
Map.addLayer(categorical, categoricalVisParams(colorByValue))

function categoricalVisParams(colorByValue) {
  // Pad the palette when using non-consecutive values instead of remapping or using sldStyle
  // to preserve the class values in the image, for inspection
  function sequence(start, end) {
    return Array.apply(null, {
        length: end - start + 1
      })
      .map(function(_, i) {
        return i + start
      })
  }

  var values = Object.keys(colorByValue)
  var palette = values.map(function (value) {
    return colorByValue[value]
  })
  var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, values)
  var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, values)
  var paddedPalette = sequence(minValue, maxValue).map(function () {
    return '#000000'
  })
  values.forEach(function (value, i) {
    paddedPalette[value - minValue] = palette[i]
  })
  return {
    min: minValue,
    max: maxValue,
    palette: paddedPalette
  }
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b434599f7345a620363b411856e77264

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that. I really appreciate the clarification on what sldStyle() actually does (creates a new image).

Comment: Daniel, in the case of a continous map, I did this: function updateassimlayer(value){
  var assim = assimslider.getValue();
  assimvisparams = {min: -assim, max:assim, palette:assimpalette};
  assimdeltahslayer.setVisParams(assimvisparams);
  assimlabel1.setValue(-assim.toFixed(1));
  assimlabel3.setValue(assim.toFixed(1));
}

Comment: I updated the answer.